# One to one relationships with one type in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, one-to-one

I have my main class:
`Person`
 and some Additional classes:
 `AddressInfo` and `DocumentInfo`.
How do I configure my relationship so it will work like `Person` with 2 addresses and 3 documents?
It's not arrays. It's named links.

Looks like:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual AddressInfo RegistrationAddress {get;set;}
    public virtual AddressInfo ResidenceAddress {get;set;}
}
public class AdressInfo
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual Person Person {get;set;}
}
```

Same with `DocumentInfo`.
It can be not even close to right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It work for me. I did not do the attribute but the code first api works better for me

```
namespace OneToOne
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (var db = new MyContext())
            {

                var person = new Person();


                db.Persons.Add(person);
                db.SaveChanges();


                person = db.Persons.Include("RegistrationAddress").Include("ResidenceAddress").FirstOrDefault();

                var address = new AdressInfo { Person = person };
                person.RegistrationAddress = address;
                person.ResidenceAddress = address;

                db.Persons.Attach(person);
                db.SaveChanges();


            }
        }
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet Persons { get; set; }
        public DbSet AdressInfos { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AdressInfoConfig());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonConfig());
        }

    }

    public class PersonConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration
    {

        public PersonConfig()
        {
            this.ToTable("Persons");
            this.HasKey(x => x.Id).Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        }

    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual AdressInfo RegistrationAddress { get; set; }
        public virtual AdressInfo ResidenceAddress { get; set; }
    }

    public class AdressInfo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    }

    public class AdressInfoConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration
    {

        public AdressInfoConfig()
        {
            this.ToTable("AdressInfos");
            this.HasKey(x => x.Id).Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            this.HasOptional(x => x.Person).WithOptionalDependent(x => x.RegistrationAddress).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            this.HasOptional(x => x.Person).WithOptionalDependent(x => x.ResidenceAddress).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried Your solution.
Thats my models:
`

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string IdentificationNumber { get; set; }
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool DeadHead { get; set; }
    public virtual PassportInfo Passport { get; set; }
    public virtual PassportInfo DriverLicense { get; set; }
    public virtual PassportInfo PensionCertificate { get; set; }
    public virtual AddressInfo ResidenseAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual AddressInfo RegistrationAddress { get; set; }
}

public class PassportInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Series { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string IssuedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime IssueDate { get; set; }



    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}



public class AddressInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Index { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string District { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Locality { get; set; }
    public int House { get; set; }
    public int Apartment { get; set; }

    public int? StreetTypeId { get; set; }
    public StreetType StreetType { get; set; }

    public int? LocalityTypeId { get; set; }
    public LocalityType LocalityType { get; set; }


    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

}
```

`
And thats my context config:

```
public class InsuranceContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AddressInfo> AddressInfos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PassportInfo> PassportInfos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LocalityType> LocalityTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<StreetType> StreetTypes { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AddressInfoConfig());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonConfig());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PassportInfoConfig());
        }
    }

    public class PersonConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
    {
        public PersonConfig()
        {
            this.ToTable("People");
            this.HasKey(x => x.Id)
                .Property(x => x.Id)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        }
    }

    public class AddressInfoConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<AddressInfo>
    {
        public AddressInfoConfig()
        {
            this.ToTable("AddressInfos");
            this.HasKey(x => x.Id).Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            this.HasOptional(x => x.Person).WithOptionalDependent(x => x.RegistrationAddress).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            this.HasOptional(x => x.Person).WithOptionalDependent(x => x.ResidenseAddress).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }

    public class PassportInfoConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<PassportInfo>
    {
        public PassportInfoConfig()
        {
            this.ToTable("PassportInfos");
            this.HasKey(x => x.Id).Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            this.HasOptional(x => x.Person).WithOptionalDependent(x => x.Passport).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            this.HasOptional(x => x.Person).WithOptionalDependent(x => x.DriverLicense).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            this.HasOptional(x => x.Person).WithOptionalDependent(x => x.PensionCertificate).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }
```

Btw it throws exception "Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong." when i try to use context or update a base with migration.